# how to connect and save the signup data(username and password) to azure database in xamarin forms

Tags: database, azure, xamarin

I have tried many times and follow the online guildlines as well , i could have connected to the azure database , however the steps to me are all not clear, can someone explain to me step by step how to save the login data into azure database

Comment: please explain to us what you have already done and what SPECIFICALLY you are having problems with.  If the existing online guides aren't helping, then having someone  write yet another step-by-step guide for you would be a waste of their valuable time.

Comment: I find kind of strange that the Xamarin app is communicating directly with the DB, it requires opening IP addresses for each user that uses the app. A better way might be to build a Web API layer which in turn talks to the DB